# How to partially use Hazelcast with Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring-data, hazelcast

I have a somehow complex application, with a dozen of entities, some of them related in a several-layer hierarchy.

I am trying to introduce Hazelcast for one of the entities, `Post`. That is, I annotated the instance with `@KeySpace`, implemented `Comparable`, `Serializable` and made its repository, `PostRepository` extend `KeyValueRepository`, all as explain in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0qlIPXkb-4.

This entity has relations to several other entities, for instance it has a property `private List<PostComment> comments`.

Now, when I fetch a post from `PostRepository`, I notice that Hibernate keeps printing the query to fetch it, several joins for the related entities as `select ... from post post0_ left outer join post_comment...`. I am assuming that Hibernate printing this means that is going to DB and not fetching the data from Hazelcast.

My question is, how do I configure that these entities are also cached by Hazelcast?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd also need to mark all related entities with `@KeySpace`. Otherwise it will always need to take the relationships directly from the database.

[Here's a good Code Sample](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/spring-data-jpa-hazelcast-migration) of adding Hazelcast as a layer in-between the application and database.

In other words, I don't think you can use Spring Data Hazelcast only for part of connected entities.